# bash script to count responses containing error text - command not executed

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

I need to request a page n times and count the number of error-pages returned

```
ITERATIONS=100000
COUNTER=0; 
COUNT_ERROR=0; 
COUNT_EXPECTED=0; 
while (( $COUNTER < $ITERATIONS )); do 
COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1)); 
curl http://www.example.com/example/path | grep -cim1 error; 
if (( $? == 0 )); then 
COUNT_ERROR=$((COUNT_ERROR + 1)) 
else 
COUNT_EXPECTED=$((COUNT_EXPECTED + 1))
fi; 
sleep 0.1; 
done; 
echo COUNT_ERROR=$COUNT_ERROR COUNT_EXPECTED=$COUNT_EXPECTED
```

This script is returning

```
COUNT_ERROR=0 COUNT_EXPECTED=0
```

... so the if clause is not executing as expected

Here is revised version ( based on triplee's comments ) :

```
iterations=100000; count_error=0; count_expected=0; for ((counter = 0; counter < iterations; ++counter)); do if curl http://www.example.com/example/path | grep -iq error; then count_error=$((count_error + 1)) else count_expected=$((count_expected + 1)); fi; sleep 0.1; done; echo count_error=$count_error count_expected=$count_expected
```

however the output is still

```
count_error=0 count_expected=0
```

NOTE: test machines include Windows 7 w/CygWin , and MBP OSX Yosemite

Here is full output :

```
bash-3.1$ iterations=10; count_error=0; count_expected=0; for ((counter = 0; counter < iterations; ++counter)); do if curl http://www.example.com/example/path
| grep -iq jetty; then count_error=$((count_error + 1)) else count_expected=$((count_expected + 1)); fi; sleep 0.1; done; echo count_error=$count_error count_e
xpected=$count_expected
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  114k  100  114k    0     0   431k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  431k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  114k  100  114k    0     0   666k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  666k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  114k  100  114k    0     0   735k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  735k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  114k  100  114k    0     0   490k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  490k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  114k  100  114k    0     0   408k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  408k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  114k  100  114k    0     0   735k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  735k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  114k  100  114k    0     0   735k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  735k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  114k  100  114k    0     0   565k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  565k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  114k  100  114k    0     0   432k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  432k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  114k  100  114k    0     0   925k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  925k
count_error=0 count_expected=0
bash-3.1$
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your original code per se; the one-liners you posted later _shouldn't_ work, because a `;` is missing before `else`.

Comment: Maybe add `set -x` (and `curl -s` to quiet it down) and copy-paste *exactly* what you ran and what output it produced.

Comment: thanks mklement0 the missing `;` before `else` fixed it

Comment: now that it's working, i'm finding highly non-linear response curve ... 10 iterations in about 1 second, but 100 iterations is not 10 secs, more like 20 secs, and 1000 is not 100 secs, more like 5 mins

Comment: @BaltoStar: Glad the syntax issue is resolved; I've summarized the outcome in an answer; as for the timing issue: I suggest you do more investigation and then ask a _separate_ question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get some resolution:

The OP's problem was that the code, despite its multi-line presentation in the question, was being executed as a *single* line.

**Multiple commands** and even the **components of a single control-flow statement called *compound commands* in bash; e.g., `if`**, when placed **on a *single* line *must* be separated by `;`** instances, whereas a newline automatically separates statements.

The `if` compound command in bash has these parts in its if/else form:

```
if [[ ... ]]; then ...;  else ...; fi  # Note the `;` chars. separating the components.
```

Search for `Compound Commands` in `man bash` for the full story.

---

In the OP's case, a `;` was missing before an `else`, resulting in the `else` branch being interpreted as a (broken) part of the `if` branch's command; for instance:

```
$ if true; then echo TRUE else echo FALSE; fi  # note missing ';' before `else`
TRUE else echo FALSE
```

Here, the missing `;` caused the entire `else` branch to be interpreted as additional arguments for `echo`.

In other cases, *neither* branch may execute, because of a *syntax error*:

```
$ if true; then i='TRUE'  else i='FALSE'; fi
-bash: else: command not found
```

Here, the entire command broke and `$i` was never assigned.
This is what happened in the OP's case (though I'm unclear on why his output did not include the syntax error message).

---

Recommendations:

- Placing multiple commands on a single line gets unwieldy quickly; consider using multiple lines, preferably in a script file.
- Use `set -x` to debug your command to see if all parts are being executed.
- When posting code in a question, post it exactly in the form needed to reproduce the problem. If that form is too hard to parse for human eyes, post an *additional* version with better formatting (and make clear that it's just for display).
- Be sure to make clear whether your code is run *on the command line* or from a *script*.

---

[tripleee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28870074/45375) has good stylistic recommendations regarding bash code; there's one worth adding:

- In bash, you can increment variables C-style using arithmetic evaluation:

  ```
  (( ++count_error )) # alternative to count_error=$(( count_error + 1 ))
  ```

tripleee states:

> I'm not familiar with CygWin but I would be vaguely surprised if it did the right thing without a shebang -- it's probably running Bash in POSIX mode, which means many of the Bashisms will be syntax errors, or just not behave like you want.

In fact (irrespective of whether bash runs on CygWin (Windows) or on Unix):

- *Syntax-wise*, all bashisms except process substitution (`<(...)`) are still available when bash runs in [POSIX mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html); however, there are many subtle changes in *behavior*, so it's always preferable to explicitly control what mode a given script runs in.
- When bash runs an executable shell script that has no shebang line, it runs it as if the script had a `bash` shebang line; in other words: it does *not* run in POSIX mode.

Comment: please note that Windows7 CygWin bash didn't recognize `((counter++))` syntax but MSYS2 bash did

Comment: @BaltoStar: Interesting; I don't see it in my CygWin installation, which comes with bash 4.1.10 - what version do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax with double round parentheses after the `if` is weird. Anyway, the proper idiomatic way to check for success is

```
if curl http://www.example.com/example/path | grep -iq error; then
```

Checking the success or failure of `curl` would be more robust, but if the web site always returns a 200 result code, you can't do that (maybe change the site so that it truthfully reports a 4xx or 5xx HTTP error code when there is a problem then?)

As a stylistic remark, you should use lowercase for your own variables, and the `counter` loop would be more elegant as a `for` loop.

```
iterations=10000
for ((counter = 0; counter < iterations; ++counter)); do
```

The semicolons at the end of line are superfluous; you need a statement separator between statements but a newline is a valid statement separator, too.

Comment: thanks tripleee , i made the idiomatic and stylistic changes you suggested but i the output is still count_error=0 count_response=0

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/2cpXV9) here.  How are you running the script?  Does it have a valid [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)?

Comment: i'm running on CygWin bash on Windows 7 - do i still need shebang ?

Comment: i added echo to the if/else and output shows neither clause is being executed

Comment: Sounds like something more fundamental then.  I'm not familiar with CygWin but I would be vaguely surprised if it did the right thing without a shebang -- it's probably running Bash in POSIX mode, which means many of the Bashisms will be syntax errors, or just not behave like you want.

Comment: @tripleee: Good advice in general, but there's nothing in the OP's script that _wouldn't_ work in bash's POSIX mode (there are many subtle changes in behavior, but the only big difference is the unavailability of process substitution).

Comment: i ran on osx with same result

Comment: @tripleee: Also, bash runs shebang-less files as if a `bash` shebang line had been specified (not in POSIX mode).